# What is fadvise/madvise equivalent on windows?

Tags: winapi, unix, memory-management, portability

On UNIX, I can, for example, tell the OS that the mapping will be needed in the future with `posix_fadvise(POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED)`. It will then read-ahead the data if it feels so.

How to tell the access intend to Windows ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Beginning with Windows 8, there is the [`PrefetchVirtualMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780543(v=vs.85).aspx) function for this purpose.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to use yours instead of mine.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, as Anders mostly suggested, **there is no such method in the memory management functions available in Windows 7 and earlier**.

2 different ways exists to do something similar :

- Read the data asynchronously with [ReadFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365468(VS.85).aspx). The data might then still be in the file cache when needed later.
- Open the file with a streaming hint with the `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` attribute of [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx). Readahead would then perhaps be automatically done.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` or `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` to CreateFile()

Comment: Are that the only hinting possibilities on Windows ?

Comment: As far as hints go, I think so. You can disable caching and things like that, but some of those other flags have alignment requirements so its more than a simple hint

Comment: FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY looks useful too - according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior it tells the system to avoid writing the data to disk if there's enough cache memory available.