# Premptively getting files into Windows page cache

Tags: c, windows, performance

I have a program written in C that allows the user to scroll through a display of about a zillion small files.  Each file needs to undergo a certain amount of processing (read only) before it's displayed to the user.  I've implemented a buffer that preprocesses the files in a certain radius around the user's position, so if they're working linearly through them, there's not much delay.  For various reasons, I can only actually run my processing algorithm on one file at a time (though I can have multiple files open, and I can read from them) so my buffer loads sequentially.
My processing algorithms are as optimized as they're going to get, but I'm running into I/O problems.  At first, my loading process is slow, but when the files have been accessed a few times, it speeds up by about 5x.  Therefore I strongly suspect that what's slowing me down is waiting for the Windows page cache to pull my files into memory.  I know very little about that sort of thing.  If I could ensure my files were in the cache before my processing algorithm needed them, I'd be in business.

My question is: is there a way to persuade/cajole/trick/intimidate Windows into loading my files into the page cache before I actually get around to reading/processing them?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way to get a file into the file system cache: reading it.  That's a chicken-and-egg problem.  You can get the egg first by using a helper thread that reads files.  It would have to have some kind of smarts about what file is likely to be next.  And not read too much.

Comment: Probably it's enough to read just one byte per page (4KB?) to have the complete page read and cached.

Comment: If the method listed in the other comment doesn't improve performance, I'm going to try reading the minimal amount per block, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX system, you'd use [posix_fadvise](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_fadvise.html):

> POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED
>
> Specifies that the application expects to access the specified data in the near future.

However, that doesn't seem to exist on Windows.  [What is fadvise/madvise equivalent on windows ? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201168/1868473#1868473) has some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I will update if I end up using this and notice it actually improves performance.