# Get all lines containing a string in a huge text file - as fast as possible?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, how to read and get as fast as possible the last line (or all the lines) which contains a specific string in a huge text file (about 200000 lines / 30 MBytes) ? 
I'm using :

```
get-content myfile.txt | select-string -pattern "my_string" -encoding ASCII | select -last 1
```

But it's very very long (about 16-18 seconds).
I did tests without the last pipe "`select -last 1`", but it's the same time.

Is there **a faster way** to get the **last occurence** (or all occurences) of a specific string in huge file?

Perhaps it's the needed time ...
Or it there any possiblity to read the file faster from the end as I want the last occurence?
Thanks

Comment: The reason there was no change whether you piped to "Select -last 1" or not is because the whole file has to be processed to know which is "last".

Comment: You may need to use .NET to have some performance there: [Start reading massive text file from the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621225/start-reading-massive-text-file-from-the-end).

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
get-content myfile.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach { $_ -match "my_string" }
```

That will read your file in chunks of 1000 records at a time, and find the matches in each chunk.  This gives you better performance because you aren't wasting a lot of cpu time on memory management, since there's only 1000 lines at a time in the pipeline.

Comment: Is it possible to return nearby lines as well somehow?

Comment: Even with `-ReadCount=1000`, `get-content` still reads the entire into memory.  I ran out of memory trying to parse a 40GB file.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried:

```
gc myfile.txt | % { if($_ -match "my_string") {write-host $_}}
```

Or, you can create a "grep"-like function:

```
function grep($f,$s) {
    gc $f | % {if($_ -match $s){write-host $_}}
    }
```

Then you can just issue: `grep $myfile.txt $my_string`

Answer (score 8):

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("myfile.txt")

$lines = @()

if ($reader -ne $null) {
    while (!$reader.EndOfStream) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line.Contains("my_string")) {
            $lines += $line
        }
    }
}

$lines | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Hi @riabovil, what if i have two or more strings to search in a file (my_string, my_string1)?

Comment: too slow like 400% slower than grep

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines();`? This method is more "raw" than the PowerShell-esque method, since we're plugging directly into the Microsoft .NET Framework types.

```
$Lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines();
[Regex]::Matches($Lines, 'my_string_pattern');
```

Comment: May be slow for big files, or even crash due to out of memory exception.

Comment: this user specifically said hes using large files, why would you post a solution that "can crash if used with large files"?

Comment: if i want regex to give whole line where pattern matches how to do that [Regex]::Matches($line, 'Database:'); it should give where it matches Database: but it should give databasename as well

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to extract the lines that contained  failed and also write this lines to a new file, I will add the full command for this

```
get-content log.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
>>  foreach { $_ -match "failed" } | Out-File C:\failes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Item -Path $source\Logs\logfile.txt | Get-Content -Tail 1
```

Comment: Please clarify what this command is doing and how it differs from the existing answers