# Open and read thousands of files as fast as possible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, io, hl7

I need to open and read thousands of files as fast as possible.

I have ran a few tests on 13 592 files and found Method 1 to be slightly faster than Method 2. These files are usually between 800 bytes and 4kB. I would like to know if there is anything I can do to make this I/O-bound process faster?

```
Method 1:
    Run 1: 3:05 (don't know what happened here)
    Run 2: 1:55
    Run 3: 2:06
    Run 4: 2:02
Method 2:
    Run 1: 2:04
    Run 2: 2:08
    Run 3: 2:04
    Run 4: 2:12
```

Here's the code:

```
public class FileOpenerUtil
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fullFilePath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ReadFileToString(string fullFilePath)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Methode 1
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath))
                {
                    string fullMessage = "";
                    string s;
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fullMessage += s + "\n";
                    }
                    return RemoveCarriageReturn(fullMessage);
                }
                //Methode 2
                /*using (File.Open(fullFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} ready.", fullFilePath);
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath);
                    //Every new line under the previous line
                    string fullMessage = lines.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + s + "\n");
                    return RemoveCarriageReturn(fullMessage);
                    //ninject kernel


                }*/
                //Methode 3

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verwijdert '\r' in een string sequence
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The text that has to be changed</param>
    /// <returns>The changed text</returns>
    private static string RemoveCarriageReturn(string message)
    {
        return message.Replace("\r", "");
    }
}
```

The files I'm reading are .HL7 files and look like this:

> MSH|^~\&|OAZIS||||20150430235954||ADT^A03|23669166|P|2.3||||||ASCII
>   EVN|A03|20150430235954||||201504302359
>   PID|1||6001144000||LastName^FirstName^^^Mevr.|LastName^FirstName|19600114|F|||GStreetName Number^^City^^PostalCode^B^H||09/3444556^^PH~0476519246echtg^^CP||NL|M||28783409^^^^VN|0000000000|60011402843||||||B||||N
>   PD1||||003847^LastName^FirstName||||||||N|||0
>   PV1|1|O|FDAG^000^053^001^0^2|NULL||FDAG^000^053^001|003847^LastName^FirstName||006813^LastName^FirstName|1900|00||||||006813^LastName^FirstName|0|28783409^^^^VN|1^20150430|01|||||||||||||||1|1||D|||||201504301336|201504302359
>   OBX|1|CE|KIND_OF_DIS|RCM|1^1 Op medisch advies
>   OBX|2|CE|DESTINATION_DIS|RCM|1^1 Terug naar huis

Once I opened the file, I parse the string with [j4jayant's HL7 parser](https://github.com/j4jayant/hl7-cSharp-parser/tree/master/j4jayant.HL7.Parser) and close the file.

Comment: As to "what happened here", usually the first run is always slower than subsequent runs (because of jitter?). Try switching method 1 and 2 and you'll probably see that now the first run of method 2 will be slower.

Comment: Start by removing (or commenting out) the call to `Console.WriteLine` in Method 2. Writing to the console has a significant effect on performance.

Comment: `fullMessage += s + "\n";` `StringBuilder` should be a bit faster.

Comment: How about [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143368.aspx)?

Comment: In method 2 this line seems useless: `using (File.Open(fullFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))` because you are already using `File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath)` which already does this internally.

Comment: Your first run sounds like you've been hit by the JIT. You should always interleave your tests and throw away the results of the first one. I also count GCs and only keep those with no Gen 0 collections.

Comment: @MickyD - Really? File IO is overshadowed by an in-memory process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used 50,000 files of varying size (500 to 1024 bytes).

**Test 1**: Your method 1 `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadLine();`
Seconds: 3,4658937968113
**Test 2**: Your method 2 `File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath)`
Seconds: 5,5008349279222
**Test 3**: `File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);`
Seconds: 3,30782645637133
**Test 4**: `BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader; b.ReadString();`
Seconds: 5,85779941381009
**Test 5**: `Windows FileReader` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9wy99d.aspx)
Seconds: 3,07036554759848
**Test 6**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadToEnd();`
Seconds: 3,31464109255517
**Test 7**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadToEnd();`
Seconds: 3,3364683664508
**Test 8**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadLine();`
Seconds: 3,40426888695317
**Test 9**: FileStream + BufferedStream + StreamReader
Seconds: 4,02871911079061
***Test 10***: `Parallel.For using code File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);`
Seconds: 0,89543632235447

Best test results are **Test 5** and **Test 3** (single thread)
**Test 3** is using: `File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);`
**Test 5** uses `Windows FileReader` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9wy99d.aspx)

If you can use threads **Test 10** is by far the quickest.

example:

```
int maxFiles = 50000;
int j = 0;
Parallel.For(0, maxFiles, x =>
{
    Util.Method1("readtext_" + j + ".txt"); // your read method
    j++;
});
```

When using RAMMap to empty the standby list:

**Test 1**: Your method 1 `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath);
sr.ReadLine();`
Seconds: 15,1785750622961
**Test 2**: Your method 2 `File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath)`
Seconds: 17,650864469466
**Test 3**: `File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);`
Seconds: 14,8985912878328
**Test 4**: `BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader; b.ReadString();`
Seconds: 18,1603815767866
**Test 5**: `Windows FileReader`
Seconds: 14,5059765845334
**Test 6**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadToEnd();`
Seconds: 14,8649786336991
**Test 7**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadToEnd();`
Seconds: 14,830567197641
**Test 8**: `StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath); sr.ReadLine();`
Seconds: 14,9965866575751
**Test 9**: FileStream + BufferedStream + StreamReader
Seconds: 15,7336450516575
**Test 10**: `Parallel.For() using code File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);`
Seconds: 4,11343060325439

Comment: One thing to note:  if there are no other changes and using multiple threads speeds up the reading of data, the reading of data wasn't bottlenecked on IO.  I'd also try rerunning your **Test 10** after clearing out all caches:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing

Answer (score 1):

I have applied all code from the comments. Method 1 still seems to be the fastest.

```
public class FileOpenerUtil
{

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fullFilePath"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ReadFileToString(string fullFilePath)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            //Method 1
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fullFilePath))
                {
                    string s;
                    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        message.Append(s).Append("\n");
                    }
                    return RemoveCarriageReturn(message.ToString());
                }
            //Method 2
            /*
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fullFilePath);
                string fullMessage = lines.Aggregate("", (current, s) =>                                        current + s + "\n");
                return RemoveCarriageReturn(fullMessage);*/

            }
            //Method 3
            /*
                string s = File.ReadAllText(fullFilePath);
                return RemoveCarriageReturn(s);*/
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fullFilePath, ex.Message);
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Verwijdert '\r' in een string sequence
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The text that has to be changed</param>
/// <returns>The changed text</returns>
private static string RemoveCarriageReturn(string message)
{
    return message.Replace("\r", "");
}
```

}