# BinaryReader 30x faster after first run. Byte array still in memory?

Tags: c#, memory, binaryreader

My program reads x bytes from a file, checks if they are all zeros, repeats the process for 20.000 files, and keeps a list of the files that have non-zero bytes.
Trying to monitor performance, I made the number of bytes it checks for each file definable (byteSize).

The problem is that the first run of the program it takes ~5 minutes for it to complete (byteSize = 8192), but if I run it again it takes only 10 seconds, even if I close and restart the program, so the only cause that comes to my mind is that the byte array remains in memory.

BinaryReader is under a "using" directive, so as far as I know it should close the stream after the loop completes. So why the byte array remains? How can I delete it? I need to do it to measure actual performance each time I run the prog.

```
byte[] readByte = new byte[byteSize];

for (int i = 0; i < readCycles; i++)
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(8192 + i * byteSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(readByte, 0, byteSize);
    }

    foreach (byte b in readByte)
    {
        if (b != 0)
        {
            allZeros = false;
            break;
        }
        else
            allZeros = true;
    }

    if (allZeros == false) break; 
}
```

Comment: There's no way the byte array is recoverable in that way by your application after restarting the process. Maybe what you're experiencing is the operating system's file caching.

Comment: The *array* doesn't remain in memory (this doesn't survive process restarts) but the *file* contents does. Windows has its own file system cache for such things. Creating new files for every run should resolve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This almost certainly has nothing to do with anything .NET is doing - it'll be the file system transparently caching for you.

To test this, change your code to just use `FileStream` and simply loop over the file reading it to a buffer and ignoring the data:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(...))
{
    var buffer = new byte[16384];
    while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm sure you'll see the same result - the first read will be relatively slow, then it'll be very fast.

Comment: Confirmed in another way: I used SysInternal's [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) to clear the OS cache and the speed is back to first run.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing