# How to ensure a file is not cached before running a benchmark?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, caching, file-io

**ETA**:  It was suggested that this is a duplicate of another question that asked essentially the same question, but the answers are, unfortunately, out of date.  The one answer that gave a programmatic solution doesn't work on Windows 10.  The other answers recommend third-party tools or give suggestions for Posix or Linux.

---

I'm trying to benchmark different methods of reading files in order to learn about the overhead of the library layers built atop the OS interfaces, the effects of various access patterns, and whether "hints" available at the OS layer may or may not improve throughput for particular access patterns.

If you run a benchmark that reads a data file and then run a different benchmark that reads the same file, the second test will usually be substantially faster because much or all of the file will be in cache.

One way to remove the cache effects from the measurements is to pre-warm the cache by reading the file once before doing the measurements.  But I'm interested in the cold cache case.

How can I measure the speed of reading a file that is not already in cache?

My best idea so far:

1. Create a directory with many test files, all the same size.
2. Restart the machine.
3. Run each benchmark against a different test file.
4. Restart the machine again once each of the test files has been used.

Is there a better approach?  Is there a way to eliminate the reboots?  Can I be certain a reboot will actually purge the test files from the cache?

---

- Windows 10
- RAM: 64 GB
- Data file size: 5 GB (typical)
- I do not want to disable caching globally.
- The data files are neither executables nor DLLs, so I don't think I have to worry about Superfetch.
- I don't mind if the driver reads ahead and buffers data once the benchmark starts reading a file.  That's what would happen with a file that hadn't been touched in a very long time, and that's exactly what I want to simulate.  Using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is not the answer.
- I'm not concerned (much) about the differences between HDD and SSD.  I'm more interested in the additional costs of various programmatic interfaces than in the absolute speed.

Comment: Voting to re-open because answers in the other question are obsolete.

Comment: Does [`SetSystemFileCacheSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-setsystemfilecachesize) not work as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56217925/1889329) answer?

Comment: @IInspectable:  SetSystemFileCacheSize operates on the entire cache.  The goal is to purge the data files from cache before the test.  If you purge the entire cache, there could be a lot of file i/o churn other than reading the test file.  Another answer on that question pointed out that calling CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING purges the particular file from the cache, so you could open it and close it right before a test.  That worked for many older versions of Windows, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to an answer that said an [individual file could be purged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113153) from the Windows file cache by simply opening the file with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and then closing it again.  That behavior is undocumented, but it apparently worked on older versions of Windows.  Unfortunately it didn't have an effect for me on Windows 10.

[Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing) that were suggested involved globally disabling, limiting, or clearing file caching, which is not the scenario I was trying to simulate.

The best solution I came up with is to have the benchmark program create a new uncached test file before each measurement.

1. Use [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) with CREATE_ALWAYS and [FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#caching_behavior). ([FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#caching_behavior) is unnecessary and probably ill-advised for this purpose.)
2. Write the contents of the file with [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile).  Since there's no system buffer, it's essential that you create a buffer [aligned to the physical sector size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements) of the drive, and that the buffer is [an integer multiple of the physical sector size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements).

   Some of the Win32 APIs report the [logical sector size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskfreespacew), which *can* be different than the physical one, but I believe the logical size is always an integer multiple of the physical size, so that's fine.  The physical sector size is almost certainly 512 or 4096 bytes for any mainstream HDD or SSD.

   Since the virtual memory system uses pages that are 4096 bytes and an [allocation granularity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-system_info) that's a multiple of the page size, using VirtualAlloc should give you a properly aligned block of memory.
3. Unless the file size is exactly a multiple of the sector size, you'll have written excess data to pad out the end of the file.  Once you're done writing, and before you close the file handle, you can use [SetFileInformationByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) using [FileEndOfFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ne-minwinbase-file_info_by_handle_class) as the "class" and [FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_end_of_file_info) struct to set the actual size.

   Note that you cannot use [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) and [SetEndOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) to set the file size.  Because the file is open with no system buffering, [SetFilePointer will adjust to a sector boundary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer#remarks).
4. Close the file with [CloseHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle).

At that point, the file should be available, but not in the system's file cache, so you can execute your measurement.  Once you do, the file will (likely) end up in the cache.  So if you want to make another measurement, you'll have to again make a new, uncached file.

Obviously, creating a new file for each measurement takes time, but it's less time that having to reboot to clear the file(s) out of cache, and it's less drastic than any operation that affects then entire system file cache.